# systemd-journald.service: unit configures an IP firewall, but the local system does not support BPF/cgroup

Tags: linux, systemd, linux-kernel, firewall

I’ve just installed ubuntu 22.04 on my jetson nano. Docker does not work on 22.04,but it works on ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. I used the same kernel version for ubuntu 18,20 and 22. This :

```
Linux marietto-nano 4.9.299+ #0 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 29 14:22:17 CEST 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

so it’s not its fault if it does not work. I suppose there is some incompatibility between some component present only on ubuntu 22.04 and not on ubuntu 18 and 20. The error is the following :

```
# docker images

REPOSITORY    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
hello-world   latest    46331d942d63   13 months ago   9.14kB

# docker run hello-world

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error setting cgroup config for procHooks process: bpf_prog_query(BPF_CGROUP_DEVICE) failed: function not implemented: unknown.
ERRO[0004] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I don’t know what to do. I even tried to upgrade the docker container files following this guide :

https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_22.04&p=nvidia&f=2

so,this is what I did :

```
# curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | apt-key add -
OK

# curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu22.04/nvidia-docker.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list

# apt upgrade
```

Before the upgrade I had these versions :

```
nvidia-docker2/stable,now 2.8.0-1 all
nvidia-container-toolkit/stable,now 1.7.0-1 arm64
```

after :

```
nvidia-docker2/bionic 2.13.0-1 all
nvidia-container-toolkit/bionic 1.13.1-1 arm64
nvidia-container-toolkit-base/bionic 1.13.1-1 arm64
```

they have been upgraded,but I still see that those packages come from bionic,but I’ve used the repos of jammy

```
# curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu22.04/nvidia-docker.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
```

This is the content of the file /etc/docker/daemon.json :

```
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    }
}
```

I’m using the JetPack 4.6.3 / L4T 32.7.3. runc version is :

```
# runc --version

runc version 1.1.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
spec: 1.0.2-dev
go: go1.18.1
libseccomp: 2.5.3
```

docker version is :

```
# docker --version
Docker version 20.10.21, build 20.10.21-0ubuntu1~22.04.3
```

And anyway,even with the packages upgraded,the error hasn’t been fixed.

As a further experiment,I have purged all the packages installed for ubuntu 22.04 and I have installed the versions of the same packages which works for ubuntu 20.04. They are called like this :

```
cgroup-tools_0.41-10_arm64.deb
docker.io_20.10.21-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_arm64.deb
containerd_1.6.12-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_arm64.deb
runc_1.1.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_arm64.deb
```

but,I’ve got the same exact error as before :

```
root@marietto-nano:/home/marietto# docker run hello-world

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error setting cgroup config for procHooks process: bpf_prog_query(BPF_CGROUP_DEVICE) failed: function not implemented: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

This is the output of the “check-config.sh” script :

```
root@marietto-nano:/home/marietto/Scaricati# ./check-config.sh

info: reading kernel config from /proc/config.gz ...

Generally Necessary:
- cgroup hierarchy: cgroupv2
  Controllers:
  **- cpu: missing
  - cpuset: missing**
  - io: available
  - memory: available
  - pids: available
- CONFIG_NAMESPACES: enabled
- CONFIG_NET_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_PID_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_IPC_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_UTS_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUPS: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED: enabled
- CONFIG_CPUSETS: enabled
- CONFIG_MEMCG: enabled
```

on the logs I see these errors :

```
cgroup: cgroup2: unknown option "nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot"
cgroup: cgroup2: unknown option "nsdelegate"
cgroup: cgroup: disabling cgroup2 socket matching due to net_prio or net_cls activatn
```

what's missing here to fix Docker ? thanks.